# Error al ejecutar comando php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer

Al ejecutar dentro de mi proyecto en laravel el comando php artisan me da este error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/root/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/root/blog/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /root/blog/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Comment: Y que hay en autoload.php línea 17? Es muy poca información para poder saber cual puede ser el problema y darte una solucion. Se necesita mas info

Answer (score 2):

Por los síntomas del error parece que no has obtenido las dependencias de composer, pues el archivo `vendor/autoload.php` es generado por composer al momento de ejecutar `composer install` o `composer update`.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que instalar las dependencias del proyecto. Por lo tanto ejecutando un `composer update` solucionaría tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas en Linux es tema de permisos :

```
chmod 777 <directorio> -R
```

Esto daría permisos para todos los usuarios en otro caso que es mejor práctica :

```
chmod 755 <directorio> -R
```